# Why is my webpage freezing when a filter button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

Tasked with creating a pinterest like webpage using the data from a JSON response. Each JSON object has a service_name key, which can be either manual, twitter, or instagram. I attempted to create three filter buttons so that the webpage would only display the respective data by using the on click method in jquery to pass an array to the loadData function. However, each of these buttons freeze the webpage when they are clicked.

Here is a link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/KevinM818/pen/OjMYYO

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var service = "";
  var datePublished = "";

  var manualImage = "";
  var manualText = "";
  var manualLinkText = "";
  var manualLink = "";

  var twitterUsername = "";
  var twitterTweet = "";

  var instaImage = "";
  var instaUsername = "";
  var instaCaption = "";

  var manualItems = [];
  var twitterItems = [];
  var instagramItems = [];

  function loadItems(array) {
    //Loop through the response array to load the data into the webpage
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      service = array[i].service_name;

      manualImage = array[i].item_data.image_url;
      manualText = array[i].item_data.text;
      manualLinkText = array[i].item_data.link_text;
      manualLink = array[i].item_data.link;

      twitterTweet = array[i].item_data.tweet;

      instaCaption = array[i].item_data.caption;

      if (service === "Twitter" || service === "Instagram") {
        username = array[i].item_data.user.username;
      }

      switch (service) {
        case "Manual":
          $("#main").append(
            "<div class='item'><div class='manual-item'><img src='https://image.ibb.co/g66jfQ/aff.png' alt='AFF' id='manual-icon'><img src=" +
              manualImage +
              " id='manual-thumbnail'><p>" +
              manualText +
              "</p><h4><a href=" +
              manualLink +
              " target='_blank'>" +
              manualLinkText +
              "</a></h4></div></div>"
          );
          manualItems.push(array[i]);
          break;
        case "Twitter":
          $("#main").append(
            "<div class='item'><div class='twitter-item'><img src='https://image.ibb.co/mGHqLQ/twitter.png' alt='twitter' id='twitter-icon'><h4>" +
              username +
              "</h4><p>" +
              linkifyTweet(twitterTweet) +
              "</p></div></div>"
          );
          twitterItems.push(array[i]);
          break;
        case "Instagram":
          instaImage = array[i].item_data.image.medium;
          $("#main").append(
            "<div class='item'><div class='insta-item'><img src='https://image.ibb.co/hXkc0Q/instagram.png' alt='instagram' id='insta-icon'><img src=" +
              instaImage +
              " alt='instagram image' id='insta-thumbnail'><h4>" +
              username +
              "</h4><p>" +
              linkifyInstagram(instaCaption) +
              "</p></div></div>"
          );
          instagramItems.push(array[i]);
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  function getItems() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/warm5",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        //Sort the JSON response by the date the item was published from most recent to oldest
        for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
          datePublished = response.items[i].item_published;
          datePublished = new Date(datePublished.substring(0, 10));
        }

        response.items.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a.item_published > b.item_published
            ? -1
            : a.item_published < b.item_published ? 1 : 0;
        });

        loadItems(response.items);
      }
    });
  }

  function linkifyTweet(text) {
    var base_url = "http://twitter.com/";
    var hashtag_part = "hashtag/";
    // convert URLs into links
    text = text.replace(
      /(>|<a[^<>]+href=['"])?(https?:\/\/([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,5}(\/[-a-z0-9!#()\/?&.,]*[^ !#?().,])?)/gi,
      function($0, $1, $2) {
        return $1 ? $0 : '<a href="' + $2 + '" target="_blank">' + $2 + "</a>";
      }
    );
    // convert @mentions into links
    text = text.replace(/(:\/\/|>)?(@([_a-z0-9-]+))/gi, function(
      $0,
      $1,
      $2,
      $3
    ) {
      return $1
        ? $0
        : '<a href="' +
            base_url +
            $3 +
            '" title="Follow ' +
            $3 +
            '" target="_blank">@' +
            $3 +
            "</a>";
    });
    // convert #hashtags into tag search links
    text = text.replace(/(:\/\/[^ <]*|>)?(\#([_a-z0-9-]+))/gi, function(
      $0,
      $1,
      $2,
      $3
    ) {
      return $1
        ? $0
        : '<a href="' +
            base_url +
            hashtag_part +
            $3 +
            '" title="Search tag: ' +
            $3 +
            '" target="_blank">#' +
            $3 +
            "</a>";
    });

    return text;
  }

  function linkifyInstagram(text) {
    var base_url = "http://instagram.com/";
    var hashtag_part = "explore/tags/";
    // convert @mentions into links
    text = text.replace(/(:\/\/|>)?(@([_a-z0-9-]+))/gi, function(
      $0,
      $1,
      $2,
      $3
    ) {
      return $1
        ? $0
        : '<a href="' +
            base_url +
            $3 +
            '" title="Follow ' +
            $3 +
            '" target="_blank">@' +
            $3 +
            "</a>";
    });
    // convert #hashtags into tag search links
    text = text.replace(/(:\/\/[^ <]*|>)?(\#([_a-z0-9-]+))/gi, function(
      $0,
      $1,
      $2,
      $3
    ) {
      return $1
        ? $0
        : '<a href="' +
            base_url +
            hashtag_part +
            $3 +
            '" title="Search tag: ' +
            $3 +
            '" target="_blank">#' +
            $3 +
            "</a>";
    });

    return text;
  }

  getItems();
  console.log(manualItems);
  console.log(twitterItems);
  console.log(instagramItems);

  $("#manualBtn").on("click", function() {
    $("#main").html("");
    loadItems(manualItems);
    manualItems = [];
  });

  $("#twitterBtn").on("click", function() {
    $("#main").html("");
    loadItems(twitterItems);
    twitterItems = [];
  });

  $("#instagramBtn").on("click", function() {
    $("#main").html("");
    loadItems(instagramItems);
    instagramItems = [];
  });

  $("#loadMore").on("click", getItems);
});
```

Comment: For whatever reason your for loop is endless.

Comment: before hitting your loop, find out what `array.length` is, it might be really high.

Comment: Did the fiddle below help you out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forked your codepen with the working fiddle. The problem was actually quite simple to find.

While your `for-loop` runs you populate the source Array in your switch statements over and over again. So I created a second argument for your `loadItems` function called "`is_filter`". When you click on one of your filter buttons we pass `true` as value. If the value is set we just ignore populating the source Array in the `for-loop`. Hope this helps you get going in the right direction:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdrgpp

This is an excerpt from one of the filters:

```
loadItems(manualItems, true);
```

And the function declaration:

```
function loadItems(array, is_filter = false) { ...
```

And here you have the inline fiddle:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var service = "";
    var datePublished = "";

    var manualImage = "";
    var manualText = "";
    var manualLinkText = "";
    var manualLink = "";

    var twitterUsername = "";
    var twitterTweet = "";

    var instaImage = "";
    var instaUsername = "";
    var instaCaption = "";

    var manualItems = [];
    var twitterItems = [];
    var instagramItems = [];

    function loadItems(array, is_filter = false) {

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            service = array[i].service_name;

            manualImage = array[i].item_data.image_url;
            manualText = array[i].item_data.text;
            manualLinkText = array[i].item_data.link_text;
            manualLink = array[i].item_data.link;

            twitterTweet = array[i].item_data.tweet;

            instaCaption = array[i].item_data.caption;

            if (service === "Twitter" || service === "Instagram") {
                username = array[i].item_data.user.username;
            }

            switch (service) {
                case "Manual":
                    $("#main").append("<div class='item'><div class='manual-item'><img src='https://image.ibb.co/g66jfQ/aff.png' alt='AFF' id='manual-icon'><img src=" + manualImage + " id='manual-thumbnail'><p>" + manualText + "</p><h4><a href=" + manualLink + " target='_blank'>" + manualLinkText + "</a></h4></div></div>");
                if(!is_filter){
                  manualItems.push(array[i]);
                }
                    break;
                case "Twitter":
                    $("#main").append("<div class='item'><div class='twitter-item'><img src='https://image.ibb.co/mGHqLQ/twitter.png' alt='twitter' id='twitter-icon'><h4>" + username + "</h4><p>" + linkifyTweet(twitterTweet) + "</p></div></div>");
                if(!is_filter){
                    twitterItems.push(array[i]);
                }
                    break;
                case "Instagram":
                    instaImage = array[i].item_data.image.medium;
                    $("#main").append("<div class='item'><div class='insta-item'><img src='https://image.ibb.co/hXkc0Q/instagram.png' alt='instagram' id='insta-icon'><img src=" + instaImage + " alt='instagram image' id='insta-thumbnail'><h4>" + username + "</h4><p>" + linkifyInstagram(instaCaption) + "</p></div></div>");
                if(!is_filter){
                    instagramItems.push(array[i]);
                }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    function getItems() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/warm5",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                //Sort the JSON response by the date the item was published from most recent to oldest
                for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
                    datePublished = response.items[i].item_published;
                    datePublished = new Date(datePublished.substring(0, 10));
                }

                response.items.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return (a.item_published > b.item_published) ? -1 : ((a.item_published < b.item_published) ? 1 : 0);
                });

                loadItems(response.items);
            }
        });
    }

    function linkifyTweet(text) {
        var base_url = 'http://twitter.com/';
        var hashtag_part = 'hashtag/';
        // convert URLs into links  
        text = text.replace(
            /(>|<a[^<>]+href=['"])?(https?:\/\/([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,5}(\/[-a-z0-9!#()\/?&.,]*[^ !#?().,])?)/gi,
            function($0, $1, $2) {
                return ($1 ? $0 : '<a href="' + $2 + '" target="_blank">' + $2 +
                    '</a>');
            });
        // convert @mentions into links  
        text = text.replace(
            /(:\/\/|>)?(@([_a-z0-9-]+))/gi,
            function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
                return ($1 ? $0 : '<a href="' + base_url + $3 +
                    '" title="Follow ' + $3 + '" target="_blank">@' + $3 +
                    '</a>');
            });
        // convert #hashtags into tag search links  
        text = text.replace(
            /(:\/\/[^ <]*|>)?(\#([_a-z0-9-]+))/gi,
            function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
                return ($1 ? $0 : '<a href="' + base_url + hashtag_part + $3 +
                    '" title="Search tag: ' + $3 + '" target="_blank">#' + $3 +
                    '</a>');
            });

        return text;
    }

    function linkifyInstagram(text) {
        var base_url = 'http://instagram.com/';
        var hashtag_part = 'explore/tags/';
        // convert @mentions into links  
        text = text.replace(
            /(:\/\/|>)?(@([_a-z0-9-]+))/gi,
            function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
                return ($1 ? $0 : '<a href="' + base_url + $3 +
                    '" title="Follow ' + $3 + '" target="_blank">@' + $3 +
                    '</a>');
            });
        // convert #hashtags into tag search links  
        text = text.replace(
            /(:\/\/[^ <]*|>)?(\#([_a-z0-9-]+))/gi,
            function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
                return ($1 ? $0 : '<a href="' + base_url + hashtag_part + $3 +
                    '" title="Search tag: ' + $3 + '" target="_blank">#' + $3 +
                    '</a>');
            });

        return text;
    }

    getItems();
  
    $("#manualBtn").on('click', function(){
     $("#main").html("");
     loadItems(manualItems, true);
     manualItems = [];
    });

    $("#twitterBtn").on('click', function(){
     $("#main").html("");
     loadItems(twitterItems, true);
     twitterItems = [];
    });

    $("#instagramBtn").on('click',function(){
     $("#main").html("");
     loadItems(instagramItems, true);
     instagramItems = [];
    });

    $("#loadMore").on("click", getItems);

});
```

```css
.buttonGroup {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 30px auto; }

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -moz-column-width: 330px;
  -webkit-column-width: 330px;
  column-width: 330px;
  -moz-column-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  column-count: 5;
  -moz-column-gap: 5px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
  column-gap: 5px; }

.item {
  position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 0; }

.item:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: rgba(222, 234, 237, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); }

.manual-item {
  width: 330px;
  border: 1px solid #dae3e5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 27px; }
  .manual-item #manual-icon {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 40px;
    margin-bottom: -66px;
    z-index: 1; }
  .manual-item #manual-thumbnail {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px; }
  .manual-item p {
    font-size: 1em; }
  .manual-item h4 a {
    color: red; }

.twitter-item {
  width: 330px;
  border: 1px solid #dae3e5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 27px; }
  .twitter-item #twitter-icon {
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 42px;
    margin-bottom: -35px;
    z-index: 1; }
  .twitter-item h4 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    text-align: center; }
  .twitter-item p {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0; }
    .twitter-item p a {
      color: red; }

.insta-item {
  width: 330px;
  border: 1px solid #dae3e5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 27px; }
  .insta-item #insta-icon {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 40px;
    margin-bottom: -66px;
    z-index: 1; }
  .insta-item #insta-thumbnail {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px; }
  .insta-item h4 {
    font-weight: bold; }
  .insta-item p {
    font-size: 1.25em; }
    .insta-item p a {
      color: red; }

.buttonWrapper {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="buttonGroup">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button id="manualBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Manual</button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button id="twitterBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Twitter</button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button id="instagramBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Instagram</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="main">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonWrapper">
        <button id="loadMore" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Load More</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Worked great. Thanks a lot for your help.